# empty result while joining three tables mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi all I have the following query

```
SELECT MAX(s.nextPass), st.ID, st.fio 
FROM recomission s 
JOIN recomission_to_student b 
     ON s.ID = b.recomission_id 
JOIN student st 
     ON  b.student_id = st.id 
JOIN education_to_student e 
     ON s.ID = e.education_id 
JOIN education ed 
     ON  e.student_id = ed.id 
WHERE s.nextPass BETWEEN  '2015-11-09' AND  '2016-02-09'
GROUP BY st.fio
```

The tables are: recomission, student and education they are related using bridge tables lide recomission_to_student, education_to student. The query works just fine until I am trying to fetch departmant from education table but then I do it query returns null. I do understand that I somewhere close to desition but still can't figureout what to do.

as for now trying to bypass the problem using subquery instead of join

```
SELECT MAX(s.nextPass), st.ID, st.fio 
FROM recomission s 
JOIN recomission_to_student b 
     ON s.ID = b.recomission_id 
JOIN student st 
     ON  b.student_id = st.id 

WHERE (select education_id where student_id=st.ID) and  s.nextPass BETWEEN  '2015-11-09' AND  '2016-02-09'
```

and getting the following error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where student_id=st.ID)' at line 8

Comment: we need to see the tables records/rows

Comment: Sorry can't figure out how to insert tables here. But I could say that if you query tables separatly it works fine or even if you join for example student table amd education it works too.

Comment: you dont need to put in the complete tables. just give a few excerpts of the data that should be in and some excerpts of data that should be out. put that in as a text table and do it as "code". that should be enough. But one thing though Modify all data so that there are no real names, passwords,.... (seen it often enough that ppl then copy&paste the real data thus saying)

Comment: one question though: are you SURE that the query works at all? I ask as: You group by st.fio  and use max(s.nextPass). That is ok BUT you also select st.fio (that is ok because of the group by) and st.ID (that one is not mentioned in the group by and is no sum,max,.... so theoretically sql should throw an error there)

Comment: Yes it works without education table.

Comment: then the main question would be if there is data that fullfills the join statement (also responding here to your comment on my answer)

Answer (score 0):

run the query only on recomission table , if you received results probably you have problems with your joins between the tables

```
SELECT MAX(s.nextPass) , st.fio 
FROM recomission s 
WHERE s.nextPass

BETWEEN  '2015-11-09'
AND  '2016-02-09'
GROUP BY st.fio
```

Comment: That's exectly where problem is... But question is why it could happen? query that you gave me works okey.

Comment: can it be that the select for st.id throws the problem?

Comment: because for at least one of your join are incorrect , try each time to add one table till you received null results

Comment: @user3600910 can it be that the select st.id is the error? never seen a select working where a group by is made and the select having something that is neither aggregate nor group by part

Comment: if any field in the select not exists you will received an error , but you will not received null values , also you need to add him to the group by

Comment: so st.id is department?

Comment: if you had problem with the group by you should received for at least one row but not null, you need to check your join

Comment: try to run the query each time add one table till you received null values , than you will now witch join is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your query has an error in regards to grouping. You select MAX(s.nextPass) and st.fio which is ok as MAX is a group function (aggregate function) and st.fio is mentioned in the group by.

BUT st.ID is neither a group function nor is it mentioned in the group by. Thus your query should return an error. The null could be caused because of this error (although normally I would expect an error message instead there).

```
SELECT MAX(s.nextPass) ,st.ID, st.fio FROM recomission s JOIN recomission_to_student b ON s.ID = b.recomission_id 
JOIN student st ON  b.student_id = st.id 

JOIN education_to_student e ON s.ID = e.education_id 
JOIN education ed ON  e.student_id = ed.id 

WHERE s.nextPass

BETWEEN  '2015-11-09'
AND  '2016-02-09'
GROUP BY st.fio
```

Thus either you change the group by to:

GROUP BY st.fio, st.id

or remove `st.ID` from the select.

Answer (score 0):

Your table :

`s, b, st, e, ed`

There are this tables have `s=b, b=st` and `s=e, e=ed` this equations.

You must check this equations and are you sure for `s.nextpass between '2015-11-09' and '2016-02-09'` this condition, maybe there are no records ?

Comment: Yes there are this condition. Without joining education it works.

Comment: Education table have data ?

Comment: Yes it does. and for selected students too

Comment: So `b.recomission_id`  and `e.education_id ` is same, is it right ?

Comment: No it isn't education_id must be responsible for department

Comment: So you use this equations `s.ID = b.recomission_id ` and `s.ID = e.education_id `. Maybe problem is there ..